# codeigniter is_unique database setup

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone assist me on the use of the is_unique function for form validation using codeigniter?
Here is my code:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

How do I set users.email?

Comment: what CI version are you using..?

Answer (score 3):

You must have a `users` table in your database, containing an `email` field.

Answer (score 1):

**is_unique** was added in CI 2.1.0. If you are using lower versions, then i suggest you look at this link: [is_unique Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/206755/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="email" />
```

must corrispond with you users table

```
`email varchar(128) not null unique`
```

then your rules, no params passed if NOT A CALLBACK!!

```
rules=>'trim|required|max_length[128]|valid_email|is_unique'
```